# Node-Oauth authentication problems; access token possibly not being passed on redirect?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, quickbooks

I'm building a React-Node app to consume QuickBooks APIs using OAuth 2 authentication. The app is structured so that the react app runs off a dev server at localhost:3000, and proxies http requests to the express server at localhost:3001.

So, I'm having some trouble making API calls: the react component responsible for rendering API data is crashing, and I'm getting the following error

> "Missing required parameter: access_token"

I have the following code in my express server, which converts the authorization code into an access token, and then (I think) passes that token to `http://localhost:3000/companyInfo`. However I suspect this is where the problem is - is the token actually being sent to this address, or have I misunderstood how OAuth works? Here's the server-side code in question:

```
app.get("/callback", function (req, res) {
  oauthClient
    .createToken(req.url)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/companyInfo" );
});
```

...here's my entire server:

```
const express = require("express");
const OAuthClient = require("intuit-oauth");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
let oauth2_token_json = null;
let oauthClient = null;

app.get("/authUri", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
    clientId: "****",
    clientSecret: "****",
    environment: "sandbox",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3001/callback",
  });
  let authUri = oauthClient.authorizeUri({
    scope: [OAuthClient.scopes.Accounting],
    state: "testState",
  });
  res.send(authUri);
});

app.get("/callback", function (req, res) {
  oauthClient
    .createToken(req.url)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/companyInfo" );
});

app.get("/getCompanyInfo", (req, res) => {
  let companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;

  let url =
    oauthClient.environment == "sandbox"
      ? OAuthClient.environment.sandbox
      : OAuthClient.environment.production;

  oauthClient
    .makeApiCall({
      url: url + "v3/company/" + companyID + "/companyinfo/" + companyID,
    })
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      console.log(
        "The response for API call is :" + JSON.stringify(authResponse)
      );
      res.send(JSON.parse(authResponse.text()));
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

...and here's the react component where I want to render the returned API call data:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const CompanyInfo = () => {

    const [ info, setInfo ] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/getCompanyInfo')
        .then(res => setInfo(res.data))
    },[])

    return(
        <div>
           <p> {info.CompanyInfo.CompanyName} </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompanyInfo
```

The strange this is that sometimes I have been able to render the API call data in this component, but I can only do it once. If I refresh my page, it crashes, and I have to start the login process again in order to make the API call work.

Comment: Your request to the API needs to include an authorization header with a bearer token of your access token.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. Did you mean including something like 'req.headers.authorization = oauth2_token_json' in my express api call? I'm still a bit new to this so not entirely clear on what you meant.